# Returning sum of row values and row count

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, jooq

I have a query to return the sum of the values in a table column. I'd like to now also return the row count.

Here is what my current query looks like:

```kotlin
db.select(DSL.coalesce(DSL.sum(AMOUNT), 0).cast(Long::class.java))
                .from(this.innerJoin(ACCOUNT).on(ACCOUNT_ID.eq(ACCOUNT.ID)))
                .where(ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_ID.eq(accId))
                .awaitSingle()
                .value1()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just [add another aggregate function to the same jOOQ query](https://blog.jooq.org/how-to-calculate-multiple-aggregate-functions-in-a-single-query/), e.g.:

```kotlin
val (sum, count) = 
db.select(
     coalesce(sum(AMOUNT), 0).coerce(Long::class.java),
     count())
  .from(this.innerJoin(ACCOUNT).on(ACCOUNT_ID.eq(ACCOUNT.ID)))
  .where(ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_ID.eq(accId))
  .awaitSingle()
```

This answer assumes the usual `import org.jooq.impl.DSL.*`